# My DBHelper and Fragment don't get along argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

First time ask here, so please be strict to me. :)

So many times the questions was asked but I still can't get a clue what is wrong in my case.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hfad.mydic, PID: 4481
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
        at com.hfad.mydic.DBHelper.getSentence(DBHelper.java:100)
        at com.hfad.mydic.DetailFragment.onViewCreated(DetailFragment.java:61)

...

Here my DBHelper

```
public ArrayList<String> getSentence(int dicType) {
    String tableName = getTableName(dicType);
    String q = " SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q, null);

    ArrayList<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        source.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_text)));
    }
    return source;
}

public Sentence getSentence(String id, int dicType) {
    String tableName = getTableName(dicType);
    String q = " SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE upper([id])=upper('?')";
    Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q, new String[]{id}); //What is wrong here?

    Sentence sentence = new Sentence();
    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        sentence.id = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COl_id));
        sentence.textlanguage = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_text));
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

private String DFvalue = "";
private TextView tvWord;
private ImageButton btnBookmark, btnVolume;
private WebView tvWordTranslate;
private DBHelper mDBHelper;
private int mDicType;

public DetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static DetailFragment getNewInstance(String value, DBHelper dbHelper, int dicType) {
    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
    fragment.DFvalue = value;
    fragment.mDBHelper = dbHelper;
    fragment.mDicType = dicType;
    return fragment;
}

...



@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tvWord = view.findViewById(R.id.tvWord);
    tvWordTranslate = view.findViewById(R.id.tvWordTranslate);
    btnBookmark = view.findViewById(R.id.btnBookmark);
    btnVolume = view.findViewById(R.id.btnVolume);

    Sentence sentence = mDBHelper.getSentence(DFvalue, mDicType); //What is wrong here?
    tvWord.setText(sentence.id);
    tvWordTranslate.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sentence.textlanguage, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    Sentence bookmarkSentence = mDBHelper.getSentenceFromBookmark(DFvalue);
    int isMark = bookmarkSentence == null ? 0 : 1;
    btnBookmark.setTag(isMark);

    int icon = bookmarkSentence == null ? R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border : R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill;
    btnBookmark.setImageResource(icon);

    btnBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int i = (int) btnBookmark.getTag();
            if (i == 0) {
                btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill);
                btnBookmark.setTag(1);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border);
                btnBookmark.setTag(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters like `?` should not be in quotes. `'?'` is a literal question mark string, `?`denotes a parameter.

Comment: I am really sorry, that worked! Thank you very much.